# autoplay videos with youtube player in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am trying to autoplay youtube videos on android, which evry time i play video must press play button to play and that is a bad experince for the user, so i try many method but it dosnt work 
so please guys help me ,thanks for advise

and this is a pieace of my code

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = null;
                intent=YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(activity,DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);    
            activity.startActivity(intent); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
autoplay = true;
lightboxMode = false;
intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
      this, YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID, startTimeMillis, autoplay, lightboxMode);
```

This works for me and can be found in youtube samples.

Comment: It is not auto start video can u help me.just show with play option

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:

```
createVideoIntent(Activity activity, String developerKey, String videoId, int timeMillis, boolean autoplay, boolean lightboxMode)
```

Implementation example:

```
intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID, 0, true, false);
```

You need to pass `true` for autoplay parameter